# LinkedIn Marketing API Creative Names/Text

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to use the adAnalyticsV2 with the statistics finder method to pull reports for my campaigns segmented by campaign + campaign group + creative.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#statistics-finder

It works fine for campaigns and campaign groups, I manage to find them in `pivotValues` and get their name. However for the creative name/title/subject/whatever, this is a different story.

[Result from a creative pivot (sponsored video)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktFE5.png)

I don't see how I can retrieve the same title/name/subject that I can see via the web interface.

[Web Interface adsets details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqKpb.png)

I tried many combinations with the projection/fields fields but without success so far :(.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may need to project contents in the ugc API. like below:

variables(data(*(*,directSponsoredContent, durationMicro, userGeneratedContentPost~(*)))))))